# iBooks Migrate Mavericks to El Capitain

Tags: books, migration

I have a huge library of books in iBooks which are categorised by "collections".

I'm migrating from an old MacBook with OS X 10.9, Mavericks, to new MacBook with OS X 10.11, El Capitan.

I've found all the books on the old computer within `/library/containers/com.apple.BKAgentService`.

I'm able to copy the books across fine. That works, but I would also like to have the "Categories" kept intact as well, as it took me ages to sort that out.

I've tried copying the entire folder over, but that didn't work. I also tried copying `com.apple.iBooksX` but that didn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Time Machine and Migration Assistant are not solutions I can use.

Comment: You'd better tell us _why_ you can't use Time Machine or Migration Assistant, because whatever is preventing you from using them might also prevent other proposed solutions from working.

Comment: had to remove hdd drive from old macbook. hard drive is in read only mode. all files are intact.

Comment: Get or borrow a cheap USB drive enclosure and you can mount that drive on the new MacBook and use Migration Assistant.

Comment: I have an enclosure. However the HDD is in read only mode because because the HDD is near it's last days.... (currently getting an error 

"OSX can't repair the disk....You can still  open or copy files on the disk....but you can't save files to the disk"

This error is making it very difficult for macbook to detect the drive...it does...but after about 15 minutes. When going to Migration Assistant, it does not detect the drive.

This was _why_ I advised that these options were moot...to avoid confusion.

The question remains...which files do I need to copy to restore Collection data

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I am moving data from and external Mavericks HD to a clean-installed El Capitan in a Macbook. I've copied the `com.apple.BKAgentService` and `com.apple.iBooksX` container folders, but still iBooks displays no books when opened. Is iBooks data stored in a different location on El Capitan? I want to avoid using Migration Assistant because I've long since begun using the new El Capitan, and want to be selective about what I copy over (only iBooks for now).